# Windows 7 Scripting host: there is no script file specified

Tags: windows, windows-7, scripting

My dad get this error on start up (it is a windows 7 machine):

Windows Scripting host: there is no script file specified.

how can you get rid of this error?

thx

Comment: off-topic, belongs to superuser.com? - you should check autoruns and possibly remove broken auto-started item http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb963902

Comment: how do you identify the broken items? Are they in red or?

Comment: You need to understand what they do. They are likely to be auto-launched on startup and one of them pops you up the error. It is likely that `cscript` and/or missing `.js` or `.vbs` files are involved.

Comment: Only .vbs file that is listed there is the : gathernetworkinfo.vbs. I have unchecked it in the list and restarted the machine but the same error still occurs